# Order of group $G = \{A\in M_2(\mathbb{Z}_p): \mathrm{det}A= \pm 1 \}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Also, $p>2$ is a prime number.

Firstly, it's obvious that $G \leq GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$, and we know that $|GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)|=p(p^2-1)(p-1)$.

Next, we define the homomorphic map $\varphi_1:GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)\to \mathbb{Z}_p\setminus\{0\}$, $\varphi_1 (A) = \mathrm{det} A$. The range of $\varphi_1$ is $\mathbb{Z}_p\setminus\{0\}$ and the kernel is $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$, so by the first isomorphism theorem we have that

$$
|\mathrm{Ker}\varphi_1| = \frac{|GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)|}{|\mathbb{Z}_p\setminus\{0\}|} = \frac{p(p^2-1)(p-1)}{p-1} = p(p^2-1).
$$

However, this just covers the case of matrices in $G$ whose determinant is $1$. I've tried figuring out a homomorphic map whose kernel would be the rest of $G$, i.e. those matrices whose determinant is $-1$, but I just couldn't figure it out. Such a map would be $\varphi_2 (A)=-\mathrm{det}A$, but it isn't homomorphic.

Is there any suitable homomorphic map that could help?

Or is there a different approach to this?

Comment: There is no homomorphism whose kernel is $\{A : \det A = -1\}$, as that set isn't a subgroup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** The map $$\Phi: A \mapsto \pmatrix{-1&0\\0&1} A$$ is invertible and satisfies
$$\det \Phi(A) = \det\left[\pmatrix{-1&0\\0&1} A\right] = \det \pmatrix{-1&0\\0&1} \det A = -\det A ,$$ and so it restricts to a bijection $${\det}^{-1}(1) \to {\det}^{-1}(-1) .$$

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but there are actually uncountably many such maps, it is sufficient to multiply A by a diagonal matrix whose diagonal elements are equal to -1 in product? :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "uncountably many such maps", as $M_2(\Bbb Z_p)$ is itself finite. But yes, that's sufficient, as having determinant $-1$ is the only property of the matrix $\pmatrix{-1&0\\0&1}$ we used.

Answer (score 2):

**A direct method** (Travis's answer is correct, here is another way)

we define the homomorphic map $\varphi_2:GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)\to \mathbb{Z}_p\setminus\{0\}$, $\varphi_2 (A) = \mathrm{det} A ^2$. The range of $\varphi_2$ is the entire set of non-null quadratic residues modulus $p$ let's denoted by $A_p$ and the kernel is $G$, so by the first isomorphism theorem we have that
$$
|G|=|\mathrm{Ker}\varphi_2| = \frac{GL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)}{|A_p|} = \cdots
$$
Note that $|A_p|=\frac{p-1}{2}$